# mysql is very slow on LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

I'm converting my entire site from MYSQLi to PDO.

Now I have one problem with one of my larger query's

```
SELECT
    kl.klant_id AS klant_id,
    kl.klant_naam AS klant_naam,
    kl.klant_adres AS klant_adres,
    kl.klant_postcode AS klant_postcode,
    kl.klant_plaats AS klant_plaats,
    kl.klant_land AS klant_land,
    kl.klant_telefoon AS klant_telefoon,
    kl.klant_fax AS klant_fax,
    kl.klant_email AS klant_email,
    kl.klant_contactpersoon AS klant_contactpersoon,
    gr.groep_id AS groep_id,
    gr.groep_naam AS groep_naam,
    IF(ft.factuur_isgroep>0,gr.groep_factuur_adress,ft.factuur_adres) AS factuur_adres,
    IF(ft.factuur_isgroep>0,gr.groep_factuur_postbus,ft.factuur_postbus) AS factuur_postbus,
    IF(ft.factuur_isgroep>0,gr.groep_factuur_postcode,ft.factuur_postcode) AS factuur_postcode,
    IF(ft.factuur_isgroep>0,gr.groep_factuur_plaats,ft.factuur_plaats) AS factuur_plaats,
    IF(ft.factuur_isgroep>0,gr.groep_factuur_land,ft.factuur_land) AS factuur_land,
    IF(ft.factuur_isgroep>0,gr.groep_factuur_iban,ft.factuur_iban) AS factuur_iban,
    IF(ft.factuur_isgroep>0,gr.groep_factuur_bic,ft.factuur_bic) AS factuur_bic,
    IF(ft.factuur_isgroep>0,gr.groep_factuur_telefoon,ft.factuur_telefoon) AS factuur_telefoon,
    IF(ft.factuur_isgroep>0,gr.groep_factuur_contactpersoon,ft.factuur_contactpersoon) AS factuur_contactpersoon,
    IF(ft.factuur_isgroep>0,gr.groep_factuur_bymail,ft.factuur_bymail) AS factuur_bymail,
    IF(ft.factuur_isgroep>0,gr.groep_factuur_email,ft.factuur_email) AS factuur_email,
    IF(ft.factuur_isgroep>0,gr.groep_extra,ft.factuur_opmerkingen) AS factuur_opmerkingen,
    al.alarm_ccs_type AS alarm_ccs,
    al.alarm_gprs AS alarm_gprs,
    al.alarm_gprs_provider AS alarm_gprs_provider,
    al.alarm_gprs_sn AS alarm_gprs_sn,
    al.alarm_doormelding AS alarm_doormelding,
    al.alarm_onderhoud AS alarm_onderhoud,
    al.alarm_onderhoud_laatst AS alarm_onderhoud_laatst,
    al.alarm_certificaat AS alarm_certificaat,
    al.alarm_cer_state AS alarm_cer_state,
    al.alarm_cer_uitgifte AS alarm_cer_uitgifte,
    al.alarm_risicoklasse AS alarm_risicoklasse,
    mk.pac_naam AS meldkamer_naam,
    mk.pac_clientnr AS meldkamer_clientnr,
    mk.pac_promnr AS meldkamer_promnr,
    mk.pac_backup_clientnr AS meldkamer_backup_clientnr,
    mk.pac_backup_promnr AS meldkamer_backup_promnr
FROM klanten AS kl
LEFT JOIN groepen AS gr ON kl.klant_groupid > 0 AND kl.klant_groupid = gr.groep_id
LEFT JOIN alarm AS al ON al.alarm_klantid = kl.klant_id
LEFT JOIN meldkamer AS mk ON mk.pac_klantid = kl.klant_id
LEFT JOIN factuur AS ft ON ft.factuur_klantid = kl.klant_id
ORDER BY klant_id ASC
```

The query works but on PDO it's very slow. (+/- 3sec while mysqli is less then 1sec)

Is this a known problem of PDO or is there something wrong with my query?

*I've read a lot of other poeple with simular problems but they all have more complex query's than this.*

**Solved** Thanks to cale_b. My problem was indexing my columns. I indexed all the columns on i used in the above query and now it's very fast. Thanks.

Comment: Check your indexes.  ALL of the fields in your `JOIN`s should be indexed for optimal performance.

Comment: show us the EXPLAIN of your query tho see the INDEX usage

Comment: Hmm, I never used any indexes. Never needed them. I go do some research about index. not needed. I go do some research on about that and how to use it. I don't know anything about it. Thanks